# How to implement a three.js html file to a flask template

Tags: python, flask, three.js, jinja2

I am creating a website using flask and I need to add a 3d model to my website. I have some code that can do this using three.js, however I haven't figured out to implement this code into my flask template.

Here is the flask redirect to the page that will show the model:

```
@app.route('/temp')
def temp():
    return render_template("temp.html", title="temp")
```

And here is some of the three.js code that works on its own:

```
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>

    <script>

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load('temp.glb', handle_load);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    </script>
```

The above code is able to display the model, however if I copy that code into Heart-Model.html (the file that the aforementioned flask redirect links to) the code doesn't work. Is there any way to make flask and three.js work together in this way? Or is there another way I could display my model using flask?

Edit: I've checked that the files (three.js etc.) are in the correct place so the only thing I can think it could be is some compatibility issue with flask or jinja or something

Edit: Removed unnecessary code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to put this code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>

<script>

var renderer,
    scene,
    camera,
    myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

//RENDERER
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: myCanvas,
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

//CAMERA
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(3, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

//SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();

//LIGHTS
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(light);

var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(light2);

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load('heart2.glb', handle_load);

var mesh;

function handle_load(gltf) {

    console.log(gltf);
    mesh = gltf.scene;
    console.log(mesh.children[0]);
    mesh.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
    scene.add( mesh );
    mesh.position.z = -10;
}


//RENDER LOOP
render();

var delta = 0;
var prevTime = Date.now();

function render() {

    delta += 0.1;

    if (mesh) {

        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        //animation mesh
        // mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ] = Math.sin(delta) * 20.0;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

</script>
```

Into your `Heart-Model.html` file.

---

It would be better to create a new `script.js` file and put it into your `Heart-Model.html` by using

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

But if you really need to put it into the HTML directly. You can put the contents of the body tag of your code into a new HTML file, let's name it `"_script.html"`, and then put the following code inside your jinja template where you want the html to be:

```
{% include "_script.html" %}
```

Comment: I've now tried adding the code on its own to Heart-Model.html, storing the JavaScript in a separate .js file, and storing the html in a different file. But when I load up the flask website and go to the model page it's just blank. There is no other code in the Heart-Model.html file (yet) so I don't know what's causing the problem because it works if I just run the html file on its own.

Comment: Would you mind copying and pasting the HTML source code of the blank page you're seeing?

Comment: I've updated my question, the page source shows the same code as I posted above

Comment: Yes! I hadn't thought of checking this. It turns out that it couldn't find the three.js files because for flask they apparently need to be stored in the static folder. I moved them and changed the links to them in the code and it now works. Thanks so much I've been struggling with this for so long

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I needed to store my three.js and model files in a static folder in order for them to work with flask